# 4 shots are fired from an army tank to completely blast an enemy car.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-distribution

4 shots are fired from an army tank to completely blast an enemy car.  Each shot has 3 possible outcomes - blast the car, damage it or miss it. 2 damaging shots blast the car. Find the probability that the car is blasted.

Shots that blast it and damage it are taken separately as in shots that blast also damage need not be considered.

I understand the total possible outcomes are 3^4 = 81, and have no idea how to proceed further. Help pls.

Comment: There is not enough information here.  You need the probability of each of the three outcomes from a single shot and some assumption regarding the dependence or independence of successive shots.

Comment: But this is all the book said.

Comment: Well, then you can just assign variables to those probabilities.  And, I guess, make the assumption that the shots are independent.

Comment: Okay, so the shots are independent. Then what? My main problem is I can’t move ahead since I don’t know what to do.

Comment: The posted solution is essentially complete.  Read about [Binomial Distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Let's make a simplifying assumption that the shot results are independent from the results of other shots. Let's set the probability to miss in any shot as $p$ and the probability to damage as $q$, so the probability to blast will be $1-p-q$.

Now, the only way to not blast the enemy car is to damage it once in $n=4$ attempts, or not to damage it at all, i.e., miss all 4 times. The probability to miss all times is $p^n$. The probability to damage once is given by $$\binom{n}{1} p^{n-1} q = np^{n-1}q,$$
so what would the final probability be?

Comment: Thanks! But is there a way without using a formula? Analytical reasoning?

Comment: @Dora formula comes from analytical reasoning. Damaging once means you pick which shot you will damage on (in $\binom{n}{1} = n$ ways) and then there will be a probability of exactly one damage and three misses ($qp^{n-1}$)...

Comment: Sure, but I haven’t really studied the hole n in the bracket thing yet. Then?

Comment: @Dora ok. an easier way is to think how many ways are there to choose the single shot on which you will do damage out of $n$ shots -- there are exactly $n$ ways to do that. Notation $\binom{n}{k}$ is the number of ways to choose $k$ different things from $n$ different things when the order of choice is not important.

Comment: it’s much simpler now. Thank you.